# Script for listing tables having no primary key oracle 9i

Tags: oracle-9i

I'm looking for a script to find tables within my database that have no primary key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select table_name from user_tables
minus
select table_name 
from all_constraints
 where (constraint_type ='P' ) and owner='dbSID_here'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way:

SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE table_name
NOT IN 
(
SELECT table_name FROM user_constraints WHERE constraint_type ='P' 
);

from [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1091626).